# How can I hide the alt text shown for an image?

Tags: media

When I upload an image and write text in alt field in *Basic Page*, the alt text later show up in down part of image. How can I remove it?  I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Alt text should be rendered as an attribute for img element, and as such should not be displayed except when the image cannot be loaded. Which theme are you using? Can you test on a different theme?

Comment: It is not alt field, probably title of image filed, check that too.